# trying to make c++11 interruptable thread, but always failed on template arg issue

Tags: multithreading, templates, c++11, lambda, forward

I am trying to make c++11 interruptable thread, but always failed on template arg issue.
I compiled the following code under Visual Studio 2013, and always got errors like *`Args` has not been declared*. After trying to modify some parts of it, I even caused a MS compiler crash.

```
class  interruptible_thread
{
public:

    template <class Function, class... Args>
    interruptible_thread(typename Function&& _fun, Args... _args)
        : _thread([](std::atomic_bool &f, Function&& fun, Args... args)
                  {
                      f.store(false);
                      // put interrupt flag ptr into TLS table
                      auto gd = std::this_thread::detail::thread_guard(&f);
                      try{
                          fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                      }
                      catch (interrupt_thread_exception &)
                      {
                          // log thread exit info in debug
                      }
                      catch (...)
                      {
                          // user exception handler
                      }
                  },
                  _flag,
                  std::forward<Function>(_fun), 
                  std::forward<Args>(_args)... 
                 )
    {}
    /* ... */
};

void somefun(int i){}

interruptible_thread myt(somefun,1);
```

construction with no args works well:

```
    template <class Function >
    explicit interruptible_thread(Function&& fun) :
        _thread([&]()
                    {
                        _flag.store(false);
                        // put interrupt flag ptr into TLS table
                        auto gd = std::this_thread::detail::thread_guard(&_flag);
                        try{
                            // user function
                            fun();
                        }
                        catch (interrupt_thread_exception &)
                        {
                            // log thread exit info in debug
                        }
                        catch (...)
                        {
                            // user exception handler
                        }
                    }
                ){}
```

Comment: using Args&&... instead of Args... also failed.

Comment: Please check if I didn't change the meaning of your question.

Comment: i think it is all right, thx

Comment: if you're in Visual Studio 2013, why don't you just use the PPL instead of rolling your own?

Comment: What happens if you assign to `_thread` in the constructor instead of in the initializer list?

Comment: You need to wrap `_flag` in a reference wrapper: `std::ref(_flag)` Otherwise, it won't be passed by reference, and cannot bind to the `std::atomic_bool&` parameter of the lambda.

Comment: The `typename` in `typename Function&& _fun` is illegal and should just be removed.

Comment: thanks Dmitry , i search PPL and find it's a good option, But, i just want to make my own interruptable thread in c++11, instead of using boost::thread or other lib.  i think c++11 can do this easily , and it's worthy to study

Comment: thanks dyp, indeed _flag issue is ok for vs2013 ; typename Function&& is a mistake , i remove it and still failed.

Comment: Yes, there's still a problem with forwarding that I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Hmm. The problem seems to be the function pointer. You pass the function `somefun` by reference, but the `thread` object tries to store it by value. This leads to decaying the function reference to a function pointer; this pointer then cannot bind to the lambda parameter (a reference again).

Comment: i updated my question , pasted a none-arg mode constructor , it works well.  with it , at least i can write code like: interruptible_thread t(std::bind(some_fun,1));  but this is not grace

Comment: If [this program](http://ideone.com/fDRIEF) does not compile under VS2013, it is most probably a VS2013 bug. (The program exits with an exception/`std::abort`, but it should compile.)

Comment: hi dyp, i tried using decay_copy(forword(fun)) , but still failed. can you try to find a solution . this is an interesting issue , right : )

Comment: I think the simplest solution to the problem of the function pointer decaying is to take `Function` by value. The same applies to `Args` of course. You'll end up with one additional move, but the alternative is to use a complicated metafunction.

Comment: thx dyp, your code works well , and i really think i have tried to compile the same code . confused!

Comment: hi dyp, it's still not work. i made a mistake in verifing your code and not cover the right route. problem STILL EXIST . i don't have other compile , can you try to compile it in some other c++11 compiler ?

Comment: If my program as linked above does not compile under VS2013, then please post the precise error messages. It is most likely a VS2013 bug; there are several known bugs related to variadic templates. Make sure you have Update 2 or Update 3 RC installed.

Comment: Note that my program passes a lambda instead of a function pointer. You can still use a function pointer if you pass by-value to the lambda, as I said earlier. This still requires a minor adjustment in the lambda's parameter types: they need to be decayed [Live example](http://ideone.com/z0jia2)

Comment: my vs2013 has update 2; and your Live example got error message: Error C2065: "Args": identifier not declared

Comment: i tried compile it in MinGW gcc 4.8 , and it's nicely supported . i really don't understand why Microsoft support c++11 so weak ... , VS is not worthy it's price .